# PERL Regex Negation Issue

Tags: regex, perl

I have written a regex to pick files of the format 
`(ABC.*\.DAT)` in perl.

How to write a negation for the above regex?

I already tried expressions like `(?!ABC.*)\.DAT` or `(?!(ABC.*\.DAT))`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: waiting for @Avinash Raj to answer it :)

Comment: Why don't you simply use `!~` instead of `~` as the regex application operator?

Comment: @BhargavModi question is unclear for me. I think he wants this `^(?!ABC.*\.DAT$).*\.DAT$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I meant I don't want to match any files matched by '(ABC.*\.DAT)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?s:(?!ABC).)*\.DAT
```

You can try this negation based regex. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/107).

The above can be safely embedded into a larger pattern. For example,

```
/^(?:(?!ABC).)*\.DAT\z/s
```

If you are trying to match the whole input, and if `ABC` doesn't end with `.`, `.D`, `.DA` or `.DAT`, then the following will be faster:

```
/^(?!.*ABC)\.DAT\z/s
```

Comment: @maverick_27 did you want to allow `ABC` at the middle?

Comment: Nope..it shouldn't allow the pattern ABC in the filename.... I tested that too...

Comment: @maverick_27 `^(?!.*ABC).*\.DAT$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj will test that and get back to you